# Downloading file in IE doesn't work when caching enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, download, outputcache

I'm trying to fix a problem with a file download that isn't working in IE from an ASP.NET MVC application.

The controller action looks something like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public FileResult GetTemplate(int id)
    {
        var data = GetData(id);

        return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), MimeType.Csv.Type, "template.csv");
    }
```

The download is initiated using a `window.open()` call in javascript. It works fine in Firefox, but not IE. 
[image: IE download error]

If I remove the `OutputCache` attribute then it works fine in IE.

**Why does the OutputCache line break the download in IE?**

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing the `OutputCacheAttribute` line to be `[OutputCache(Duration = 1200, Location =  OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "*", NoStore = false)]`. My question still holds though, but I'm not looking for a solution or workaround. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work in IE and am looking for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your final question, you are looking for an explanation, here it is:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

This is effectively a bug in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. Don't use `window.open` but a simple download link
2. Use `application/octet-stream`:

   ```
   return File(
       Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), 
       "application/octet-stream", 
       "template.csv"
   );
   ```